# Avoiding: syntax error near unexpected token in bash

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have a shell that calls a python script like so...

Shell code:

```
#!/bin/sh
python PyTest.py

print("FE FI FO FUM I'M GOING TO MAKE IT TUMBLE TUM TUM")

5 + 4

print("No semicolons here!")
```

Python code:

```
#This is my test Python script running from bash

print("FE FI FO FUM I'M GOING TO MAKE IT TUMBLE TUM TUM")

print(5 + 4)

print("No semicolons here!")
```

And here is the output.

```
74-85-81-234:Desktop Cody$ ./PyTest.sh
FE FI FO FUM I'M GOING TO MAKE IT TUMBLE TUM TUM
9
No semicolons here!
./PyTest.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `"FE FI FO FUM I'M GOING TO MAKE IT TUMBLE TUM TUM"'
./PyTest.sh: line 5: `print("FE FI FO FUM I'M GOING TO MAKE IT TUMBLE TUM TUM")'
```

I've looked up the "syntax error near unexpected token" error and it looks like this is expected. Is there a better way to do this, and is there a way to call the function in this manner without the Bash errors?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to write python, do that and use a python interpreter. If you want to write a shell script, use a shell. Don't expect a shell to understand python or python to understand a shell script.

Comment: Why is most of the text of your "shell script" Python?

Comment: What do you expect `5 + 4` to do?  There is no assignment, no `echo` statement, and that is not the correct syntax for arithmetic in sh anyway.  Korn shell and zsh that support `print`, but it is not POSIX compliment and no parentheses are required.  Your comments says you are using bash, but you specify `/bin/sh` in your script (which might be linked to bash, but does not behave as bash).

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The immediate problem is that parentheses are not used that way in shell script (they run a command in a subshell; so the first token inside the parentheses should be a command name - but here, the problem is using parentheses where they are not correct or useful).

Comment: ... but fixing that would immediately get you in trouble with `print`, which is not a standard command (so either "command not found" or a command which might do something else than you want, possibly involving a printer and expecting a file name, or just wasting a ream of paper in a locked room in another building), and it doesn't end there.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I got it to work eventually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run a `bash` script, then specify `bash` at the top of your file, not `sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

To run a python script from bash then all you have to do is:

```
python PyTest.py
```

If you want to *embed* python in a script then you can use a here document:

```
python << END

print("FE FI FO FUM I'M GOING TO MAKE IT TUMBLE TUM TUM")

print(5 + 4)

print("No semicolons here!")

END
```

Or write it in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "FE FI FO FUM I'M GOING TO MAKE IT TUMBLE TUM TUM"

echo $((5 + 4))

echo "No semicolons here either!"
```

But why?  Bash can't do anything that python can't do, yet python can do an awful lot more than bash.  Write everything in python!  Just put something like  `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top of your python script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print("FE FI FO FUM I'M GOING TO MAKE IT TUMBLE TUM TUM")
5 + 4
print("No semicolons here!")
```

or

```
#!/bin/sh

python <<%
print("FE FI FO FUM I'M GOING TO MAKE IT TUMBLE TUM TUM")
5 + 4
print("No semicolons here!")
%
```

Note that `5 + 4` won't produce any output in either cases as this is not an interactive python session:

```
FE FI FO FUM I'M GOING TO MAKE IT TUMBLE TUM TUM
No semicolons here!
```

Using the `-i` option will make it work:

```
#!/bin/sh

python -i <<%
print("FE FI FO FUM I'M GOING TO MAKE IT TUMBLE TUM TUM")
5 + 4
print("No semicolons here!")
%
```

output:

```
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> FE FI FO FUM I'M GOING TO MAKE IT TUMBLE TUM TUM
>>> 9
>>> No semicolons here!
>>>
```